# XBee 2 Module sensor network and Python with Raspberry Pi - ONLY one Mac address from two different received samples

Tags: python, xbee

I am trying to set up a network of multiple nodes, I am receiving the different analog reading from the two end devices on the network. When I discover them both they have their separate MAC address are few and their Node ID that I configured to them. However, when I use the remote device in the io_sample_callback function it always output the same node ID. I need help! Side note I am using XBee 2 modules not the Xbee 3.  Please help, the following is the code and a screenshot of output:

*****Beginning of Code********

```
import serial
import time
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
from digi.xbee.io import IOLine, IOMode
import mysql.connector
import datetime
import csv
import MySQLdb
# Serial port on Raspberry Pi
SERIAL_PORT = "/dev/ttyS0"
# BAUD rate for the XBee module connected to the Raspberry Pi
BAUD_RATE = 9600
# Analog pin we want to monitor/request data
ANALOG_LINE1 = IOLine.DIO1_AD1
ANALOG_LINE2 = IOLine.DIO2_AD2
ANALOG_LINE3 = IOLine.DIO3_AD3
# Sampling rate
SAMPLING_RATE = 15
# Get an instance of the XBee device class
device = XBeeDevice(SERIAL_PORT, BAUD_RATE)
# Method to connect to the network and discover the nodes
def discover_nodes():
    """Get a list of the nodes (node ids) on the network
    Returns:
    """
    # Request the network class and search the network for the remote node
    xbee_network = device.get_network()
    xbee_network.start_discovery_process()
    print("Discovering network", end='')
    while xbee_network.is_discovery_running():
        print(".", end='')
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print("done.")
    devices = xbee_network.get_devices();
    node_ids= []
    for dev in devices:
        print("Found {0} at {1}.".format(dev.get_node_id(), dev.get_64bit_addr()))
        node_ids.append(dev.get_node_id())
    if not node_ids:
        print("WARNING: No nodes found.")
    return node_ids
# Method to connect to the network and get the remote node by id
def get_remote_devices(remote_node_ids):
    """Get the remote node from the network
    Returns:
    """
    # Request the network class and search the network for the remote node
    xbee_network = device.get_network()
    remote_device = xbee_network.discover_devices(remote_node_ids)
    if remote_device is None:
        print("ERROR: Remote node id {0} not found.".format(remote_id))
        exit(1)
    #remote_device.set_dest_address(device.get_64bit_addr())
    #remote_device.set_io_configuration(ANALOG_LINE1, IOMode.ADC)
    #remote_device.set_io_sampling_rate(SAMPLING_RATE)
# Method to get the data when available from the remote node
def io_sample_callback(sample, remote, time):
    address = str(remote.get_64bit_addr())
    # Get the raw temperature value
    raw_temp = sample.get_analog_value(ANALOG_LINE1)
    # Save results in the table
    short_addr = address[-4:]
    # Get the temperature in Celsius
    temp_c = (raw_temp / 1023.0 * 1.25 - 0.5) * 100.0
    # Calculate temperature in Fahrenheit
    temp_f = ((temp_c * 9.0) / 5.0) + 32.0
    print("\tTemperature is {0:.2f}C. {1:.2f}F from node {2}".format(temp_c, temp_f,remote.get_64bit_addr()))
    timenow = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO test(date_time, analog_1, analog_2, analog_3, id) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);''',(timenow,sample.get_analog_value(ANALOG_LINE1),sample.get_analog_value(ANALOG_LINE2),sample.get_analog_value(ANALOG_LINE3),remote.get_node_id()))
    db.commit()
# Connect to database server
try:
    print("Connecting to MySQL...", end='')
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="team1", passwd="team1",db="singletemp") #connects to MySQL/MariaDB
    cur = db.cursor()
    print("done.")
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    raise Exception("ERROR: Cannot connect to MySQL Server!")
    exit(1)
try:
    # Read and save temperature data
    print("Welcome to example of storing data from a set of remote TMP36 sensors in MySQL!")
    device.open()  # Open the device class
    # Get the nodes on the network
    remote_node_ids = discover_nodes()

    # Setup the remote device
    #get_remote_devices(remote_node_ids)
    device.add_io_sample_received_callback(io_sample_callback)
    # Register a listener to handle the samples received by the local device
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    if device is not None and device.is_open():
        device.close()
# Disconnect from the server
try:
    db_conn.disconnect()
except:
    pass
```

******END of CODE********

OUTPUT:

```
Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
>>> %Run pi_xbee_mysql.py
Connecting to MySQL...done.
Welcome to example of storing data from a set of remote TMP36 sensors in MySQL!
Discovering network......done.
Found South Node at 0013A20041E57931.
Found North Node at 0013A20041E57938.
    Temperature is -50.00C. -58.00F from node 0013A20041E57931
    Temperature is 23.31C. 73.96F from node 0013A20041E57931
```

Comment: Can you paste your code into the question instead of linking to screen shots?  Can you have the xbee-python library dump raw packets so you can see what it's receiving?  Or if you use Digi's XCTU utility, how does it parse the packets that come in?  Is it possible that the "North Node" isn't sending you I/O samples?

Comment: @tomlogic edited the post to have the code in there without screenshots. I am using the Digi's XCTU I am pretty sure the north node is sending the I/O sample because it seems that the node that always prints with the same is just the first node discovered on the network, so it could be the south or north. I am not sure on how to do the dump raw packets but I will look into it. Let me know if you can help me out thanks!

Comment: What happens if you just print out `remote`?  I'm wondering if you're getting a 16-bit sample, and the 64-bit address in `remote` is set to some leftover value from node discovery (either the first or last node discovered).  If you have XCTU connect to the radio module receiving the I/O samples, you can go to the terminal tab and have it display either raw packets or decoded frames.  That might help with troubleshooting.  You could also open an issue on the GitHub project page: https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-python/issues

Comment: @tomlogic thanks so much for the help and pointing me to Github, someone there was able to solve my problem. I need to channel the 16-byte address to 0xFFFF (MY setting in the XCTU configuration program). Here is a link if anyone else has this issue:
https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-python/issues/268

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by [tatianaleon on GitHub](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-python/issues/268):

Are your XBee modules 802.15.4? If so, did you configure different 16-bit addresses for your modules (MY parameter)? Or all of them to 0xFFFE?
In 802.15.4, to use long 64-bit address, MY must be 0xFFFE or 0xFFFF, otherwise modules use short source addressing (MY address).
By default, MY is 0x0000 in 802.15.4 firmware, so, by default, modules use short 16-bit addressing and 0x0000 as address.

If this is the case, both discovered nodes 0013A20041E57931 and 0013A20041E57938 have the same 16-bit address, the default one, 0x0000. So when an IO message is received from any of them, the source address is 0x0000 always and the library looks for the first discovered node with that 16-bit address.

in 802.15.4, for 16-bit addressing, you must configure all the nodes in the network with different MY values. If you prefer to use 64-bit addresses, then set the MY of all your modules to 0xFFFE or 0xFFFF.

See https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90001500/Default.htm#Reference/r_addressing_802.htm